# Братан, брательник; сеструха, сестренка — значение слов

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова, разговорная-речь

Мне попалась в одной книге информация, что такие слова, как **сеструха, сестренка** или **братан, брательник**, — это не просто разговорные формы одного слова, а различия старшинства. Мол, сеструха — это старшая сестра, а сестренка — младшая, братан — старший и т. д.
Никогда раньше ничего подобного не слышал, поэтому хочу спросить: правда это или вымысел автора?
Извините, если вопрос дурацкий.

Answer (score 1):

Вымысел автора. Но братаном где-то называют двоюродного брата – это точно.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос совсем не дурацкий. Большая личная просьба – дайте ссылку или назовите заглавие и автора «одной книги», где содержится эта информация.

Меня очень интересуют смысловые сдвиги в русском языке, спровоцированные влиянием других народов и культур. Еще в 70-е я читала в профессиональной языковедческой статье о том, что в речи некоторых людей слово «братишка» приобрело значение «младший брат». Автор связывал этот смысловой сдвиг с влиянием культур южных народов, для которых очень важна возрастная дифференциация, поскольку она является основой отношений иерархии, да и вообще в традиционных культурах очень важны родственные связи, и потому существует сложная система понятий, эти связи описывающих. Из  русского языка эти понятия давно ушли или уходят (кто сейчас может отличить шурина от деверя?), но представители Кавказа и Средней Азии, изучая русский, пытаются перевести на него понятия своего родного языка, используя для этого русские суффиксы, совершенно для другого предназначенные. Так и возникает убеждение, что  сеструха - это старшая сестра, а сестренка – младшая. Подозреваю, что употребление слова «близняшка» в значении «близнец женского пола» имеет ту же природу.

Answer (score 1):

```
    БРАТА́Н, братана, муж. (обл.). Двоюродный брат.
    || Старший брат.
    || Брат.
    || Сын брата.

БРАТИ́ШКА, братишки, род. мн. братишек, муж.
1. Маленький брат (разг. фам.).
2. Брат (прост.).
3. То же, что брат во 2 знач., но с еще большей фамильярностью (прост.). А, братишка, и ты здесь!
```

***(Толковый словарь Ушакова)***

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, что в сербохорватском языке слово "братац" вообще обозначает близкого родственника. Так муж называет жену, а мать - дочь. Видела это в объяснении [этимологии слова батя](http://educador.narod.ru/index/proiskhozhdenie_slova_batja/0-871), которое, как пишет Шанский, первоначально употреблялось как уменьшительно-ласкательная форма к "брат" (ср. старочешское bat’a — «брат»), позднее стало выполнять роль интимного названия родственника вообще, а затем в некоторых слвянских языках приобрело значение "отец".

Answer (score 0):

У Мельникова-Печерского (не помню, в какой именно книге, но "В лесах" или "На горах" точно) есть такие определения:

*братан* — старший брат, братанишна — жена старшего брата, *брательник* — младший брат, *брательнишна* — жена младшего брата

Comment: В книге "На горах". Только *братанишна* там дочь братана, а *брательнишны* я и вовсе не нашёл.